# Javascript arithmetic operator not working

Tags: javascript

```js
var sub_total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    var rate = parseFloat(10).toFixed(2); 
    var quantity = parseFloat(15).toFixed(2); 
    var sub_total = parseFloat((rate * quantity) + sub_total).toFixed(2);
  }
console.log(sub_total);
```

Expected Output:

> 450.00

Please help me How can I solve this why it giving output 150150150.00.

Comment: what is the expected value ?

Comment: It give me exact out as you wanted then what is an issue?

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns string

Comment: You will get `600.00` not `450.00`. Because loop has 4 iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Because `subTotal` is a string (since you used `toFixed`), make it

```
var sub_total = parseFloat((rate * quantity) + sub_total);
sub_total = sub_total.toFixed(2);
```

**Demo**

```js
var sub_total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var rate = parseFloat(10).toFixed(2);
  var quantity = parseFloat(15).toFixed(2);
  var sub_total = parseFloat((rate * quantity) + sub_total);
}
sub_total = sub_total.toFixed(2);
console.log(sub_total);
```

**Edit**

> Expected Output:
>
> 450.00

Change the for-loop back to

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
```

Comment: why `parseFloat` for numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the answer to your question?

As the others already said: toFixed returns a String

```
var sub_total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
  var rate = parseFloat(10); 
  var quantity = parseFloat(15); 
  var sub_total = parseFloat((rate * quantity) + sub_total);
}
console.log(sub_total);
```

Comment: Better, you need to explain what you have changed to achieve this answer.

Comment: @Durga Thank you for your hint. Others already told the solution but nevertheless I added this to mine.

Answer (score 0):

> For Expected Output: 450.00

You have to loop only `<3` then you will be get required output.

**See blow Demo**

```js
var sub_total = 0,
  rate = 10,
  quantity = 15,
  i = 0;

for (; i < 3; i++) {
  sub_total += (rate * quantity);
}


console.log(sub_total.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: dv, not me, but to much `parseFloat` for numbers in.

Comment: @NinaScholz thank for this "but to much parseFloat for numbers". Please see I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code is helpful.

```
 var sub_total = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
  var rate = parseFloat(10).toFixed(2); 
  var quantity = parseFloat(15).toFixed(2); 
  sub_total+ =parseFloat(rate) * parseFloat(quantity) + 
  parseFloat(sub_total);

  }
 console.log(sub_total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numbers without `parseFloat`. At the end, you could format the number.

You need only to iterate three times and assign the unchanging values only once.

```js
var sub_total = 0,
    rate = 10,
    quantity = 15,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    sub_total += rate * quantity;
}

console.log(sub_total.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

I have removed "<=" and replaced it with "<" since previous case leads to another iteration,because of that you get 600.00 .Also I have used toFixed method at the end, since initially we need to calculate the value of sub_total first then we have to convert it to a string having two decimals.

```
 var sub_total = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var rate = parseFloat(10).toFixed(2); 
    var quantity = parseFloat(15).toFixed(2); 
    sub_total = parseFloat((rate * quantity) + sub_total);
  }

    console.log(sub_total.toFixed(2));
```